# Cannot access NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsmutablearray

I have declared an array in a header file like this.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

And I have allocated the array in the implementation file loadview method like this.

```
myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

And then i have added some data to it from the sqlite database into the array in the same loadview method. The array retains the content only within the loadview method when i try to access it in other methods it throws an error stating that the array is empty.I tried NSlog within the loadview after loading the array with some data. It works fine within loadview method. Why it s not retaining outside the loadview method ? Can  anyone please help me out of this ?

```
NSString *myStr = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Please show us more of your code. It's hard to interpret this. Is the array an instance variable? Are you accessing it from the same instance of your class?

Comment: @jtbandes I have declared it in the header file of  a viewcontroller and then trying to access it from the implementation file. I didnt declare it as a property.

Comment: What other methods are you accessing it from? Can you show some of the code?

Comment: @jtbandes I am trying to access it from a user defined method using the above show code...

Comment: Sorry, this still isn't enough information. You need to show us your code or we can't really help.

Comment: Please add the code to show how do you create the object and how do you release the array elements.

Comment: you need to add [myArray retain] once you have added contents in the array.

Comment: @smriti I have fixed the problem. Anyway, Thanks once again.